# How to use selfextract files in a wix install

Tags: wix

I am really new using WIX, my only experience to build a complete install was with INNO, and WIX has been decided the way to go for an MSI

The installation includes a bunch of examples and templates, 427 files, which seems crazy to enumerate even with an utility like HEAT.EXE

So we went for a self-extracting utility. WIX install includes this custom utility and the compressed cabinet file, and then that extracts files and folders via custom action.

Problem is when we try to delete the compressed file and the extractor utility. I haven't found the way to delete them after the extraction takes place. `RemoveFile` seems to not work, and deleting the file within the extraction utility fires the self-healing mechanism in every run of the application.

Leaving the files in the install is dangerous, it is 200MB and it would reset all the installed examples if user runs the self-extraction utility by accident.

If it is of use, the WIX snippet in charge of this is like that:

```html
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="App_Files">
      <Component Id="cmp_Files_Dat" Directory="INSTALLCOMMONFOLDER" Guid="{8BFED6C2-4D4F-48BB-xxxx-C171F624C90B}">
        <File Id="fil_Files_Dat" Source="appfiles\files.dat" />
        <RemoveFile Id="rem_Files_Dat" Name="files.dat" On="install" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp_UnpackFiles_exe" Directory="INSTALLCOMMONFOLDER" Guid="{5722B5E0-C6E8-4C71-yyyy-61EC0ACA0D72}">
        <File Id="fil_UnpackFiles_exe" Source="appfiles\UnPackFiles.exe"  Checksum="yes" />
        <RemoveFile Id="rem_UnpackFiles_exe" Name="UnPackFiles.exe" On="install" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    <CustomAction Id="action_UnPackFiles" FileKey="fil_UnpackFiles_exe" ExeCommand="[INSTALLCOMMONFOLDER]" Execute="commit" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="action_UnPackFiles" After="InstallFiles" > NOT (REMOVE="ALL") </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Fragment>
```

The net result of the code above leaves the files, does not remove them.

Thanks in advance

Josep

Comment: Even though it seems crazy, I would say that using heat.exe is much more preferable to what you are doing. We used to do a self-extracting exe with an SDK install where I work and I rewrote the installer to use heat every run and you don't run into the problems that you are experiencing and it's also nicer to upgrade with and uninstall with. I will try to remember to put a sample <HeatDirectory> definition for automatically harvesting every build the dir that you usually make the self-extracting exe out of as an answer when I have more time.

Comment: Brian, thanks for your reply. We will rethink it. The idea behind the self extracting stuff is to have all the examples and auxiliary files packed in an easy way, eventually swapping them without the hassle of moving the entire tree structure.

Comment: After all we may want to leave the self extracting item in the installation. This contains the application examples that user can tamper with and later on reset to the original state.

Comment: On the other hand, using HEAT would add each file to the installation, This would also fire the self-healing mechanism when an example is edited. BAD. And would be removed on uninstall, which may not be that good for other applications that may eventually use these files indirectly.

Comment: I do look forward to see your proposed automatic harvesting with HEAT. That may be useful to know and eventually use in the future.  Thanks a lot !